# Why doesn't this map() or flatMap() finish the pipeline even with then()?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this method

```
private Mono<String> getToken(String id){
....
}
```

and the caller

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
getToken(id).map(s -> tokens.add(s)).then();
```

It doesn't add the returned `token` to the list
Why this pipeline never get completed, and the returned `token` never get populated into the list?

I have tried `subscribe()` and `flatMap()`, but still the issue. The only way i managed to populate the token to the list is by using `block()` which in turn did throw another exception.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you sort of answered your own question:

> The only way i managed to populate the token to the list is by using block()

You may be confusing Project Reactor API with JavaScript Promises. It doesn’t work the same way.
I highly suggest reading [the documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then--).

Indeed, **the only way to execute a reactive pipeline is to subscribe to it**. [`subscribe()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe--) does that, but is asynchronous, so it doesn’t wait for the computation to finish.
[`block()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--) is what you are looking for: it subscribes to your `Mono` and waits till it’s over.

Secondly, `map()` transforms values it receives to something else; in your case, after the `map()` you get a `Mono<Boolean>` because `ArrayList#add()` returns a boolean. If you don’t need the transformation, you can call [`doOnNext()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-).

```java
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
getToken(id).doOnNext(tokens::add).block();
```

That will execute the `Mono` and store the result in the `List` before continuing execution.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4

Comment: @MeladBasilius That’s another problem, you need to be careful where you are blocking. Why are you in thread *reactor-http-nio-4*? It means you are already in a reactive pipeline…

Answer (score 1):

The logic contained in your `getToken()` method is unknown and possibly late or invoke a synchronous service that takes time, there are things that could be different when testing.

- Do not make blocking calls in your code with reactor, you can know if you have blocking calls with the **BlockHound agent**
- Many times you will need to use a `CountDownLatch` for the subscription to complete.
- Also sleeping the main thread with a simple `Thread.sleep()` so that the subscription is terminated, but I prefer the option above it..

---

**reactor-test dependency**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

### **Basic TDD with reactor**

```
private Mono<String> getToken(String id) {
    return Mono.just(id);
}

@Test
@DisplayName("get token version 1")
void testGetToken() {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    final String ui = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    getToken("Token id " + ui)
            .map((String token) -> {
                tokens.add(token);
                return token;
            })
            //.then() From Documentation, This operator discards the element from the source.
            // do not invoke then () here it is not necessary and by the way it returns a Mono <Void> you want a String token
            .subscribe(tokenSubcription -> log.info("Token id {}", tokenSubcription));
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Get token version 2")
void testGetToken2() {
    final String ui = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    Mono<String> monoToken = getToken("Token id" + ui)
            .map((String token) -> {
                tokens.add(token);
                return token;
            });

    StepVerifier.create(monoToken)
            .expectNextMatches(e -> e.equals("Token id" + ui))
            .verifyComplete();
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Get token version 3 with CountDownLatch")
void testGetToken3() {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final String ui = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    final AtomicReference<String> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>();
    getToken("Token id " + ui)
                    .map((String token) -> {
                        tokens.add(token);
                        return token;
                    })
                    .doOnTerminate(countDownLatch::countDown)
                    .log()
                    .subscribe(atomicReference::set);
    try {
        countDownLatch.await();
        log.info("Thread in doOnTerminate {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    assertThat(atomicReference.get()).isEqualTo("Token id ".concat(ui));

}
```

**Another example without StepVerifier**

```java
private Mono<List<String>> getMonoToken() {
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final String ui = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        getToken("Token id " + ui)
                .doOnTerminate(countDownLatch::countDown)
                .subscribe(tokens::add);

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
            log.info("Thread in doOnTerminate {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return Mono.just(tokens);
}

@RepeatedTest(10)
void testMonoToken2() {
        this.getMonoToken()
                .subscribe(token -> log.info("Token id {}", token));
}
```

**Using subscribe**

```java
private Mono<List<String>> getMonoToken() {
       List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
       final String ui = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
       return getToken("Token id " + getUUI())
               .map(token -> {
                   tokens.add(token);
                   return tokens;
               });
}

@RepeatedTest(10)
void testMonoToken2() {
       this.getMonoToken()
               .subscribe(token -> log.info("Token id {}", token));
}
```

[image: imageOne]